# How would browser cookies look from TCP server point of view?

Tags: javascript, http, browser, tcp

So imagine we have TCP server recieving all browser requests. How a cookie generated by some JavaScript function like:

```
function writeCookie() 
{ 

var the_cookie = "users_resolution="+ screen.width +"x"+ screen.height; 

document.cookie=the_cookie 

location = location.href; 
}
```

Will loock  if some browser like chrome will come to such server? what will full page requesl look like?

Comment: how javascript is executed on your server?

Comment: What is your goal? There are probably better ways to do requests to your server, or even a totally different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes through as part of the HTTP request header (look at the spec or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie for a quick overview).  HTTP just looks like normal payload data as far a TCP is concerned.  I would drag out a packet sniffer and capture some traffic.

Answer (score 3):

Fire up [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and take a look.

Answer (score 2):

There will be a

```
Cookie: users_resolution=1024x768
```

header in the request.